# Hide relationship from a SQL Server database diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms, database-diagramming

I am using SQL Server 2005 database with SQL Server Management Studio.

Is there a way to hide a relationship between two tables in the diagram without actually deleting the relationship from the database? Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to? That's like saying 'this relationship is important enough to actually exist but we dont want people working with the database to know about it'.

Comment: Well in my case, people DO know about it but do not want it to be visible because it creates a lot of mess when printed. Just for readibility.

Comment: All our tables have a 'lastedited' link to user. As soon as you want to make a schema with user (for any other reason), the schema is a mess

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this without dropping the FK relationship. Short of using [tipp-ex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipp-Ex) on the monitor :-) You do this at your own risk though :-)